# On-Premise Gateway Instance not showing in Azure On-Premise Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

After i Creat On-Premise gateway localy in my computer using the same account with azure, But still i got error message that says No Installed Instance were found for ther curent users. I Already make the region same to SEA but still no instance were found . I already tried to uninstall the On-Premise gateway but the result still the same. For the reference i'm using this tutorial https://blogs.biztalk360.com/access-on-premise-sql-server-data-from-azure-logic-apps-via-on-premises-data-gateway/ .How to fix this, and what cause that happen ? and fyi im using Invitation from Default Directory to acces Azure is that what caused this ?

Comment: Gateway installations are discovered by tenant and user id, so if you installed your gateway using your identity in another tenant than you are using to log into the Azure portal, then the gateway installation will not show up.

Comment: example the real tenant id is ideapad@bla.onmicrosoft.com, this idepad invite me theo@bla.onmicrosoft.com (So i can acces Azure) then me (theo@bla.onmicrosoft.com) create local on-premise gateway and then i login using my account theo@bla.onmicrosoft.com to azure . so that doesnt work ? Do I need to create local data gateway using the real tennat id (ideapad@bla.onmicrosoft.com) and login using the real tenant id too ?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang , did you ever get this working?  I'm having the same problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The user must be created inside the same Azure directory where the gateway is created.

I was trying to use an AD account invited from another directory and it doesn't work. How can you tell if a user has been invited? The "User principal name" will contain #EXT# just before the '@' sign.

In my case the solution was to create a new AD user specifically for the gateway.